# Optimization Question about Singleton

Tags: c#, unity, performance, optimization

I am using Unity with c#.
I have two objects and one needs to call a function from the other which is a Singleton. For this I have two solutions. But what's the best thing to do :
 - Call for :
`MyScript.Instance.MyFunc();`
 - Store my Singleton object in my calling object and call it like this :
`myScript.MyFunc();`

What is the best thing to do in term of performance and optimizations.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How often do you call this code per frame? And the big pink elephant in the room: Did you profile?

Comment: This is not called very often, and no profile. My question is general but maybe it's linked with the circumstances.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995627/optimization-about-singleton . Please choose one site or the other for asking a question. In this case, this should go on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can see that answers are not the same. And I prefer to have multiple reviews. But thanks for your great answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity things are a bit different, usually this is what I go for when using the singleton design pattern:

1. Static class (`MyClass.Foo();`) - Used when creating non-Unity related, static functions. A good example would be a static data manager class that stores information about your player throughout the various scenes.
2. Mono/Singleton class inheritence (`MyClass.Instance.Foo();`) - Used when creating a static class that lives in the "Unity lifecycle", for example when you want to use MonoBehaviour's event functions (Update, Awake, etc) or using Unity's coroutines, etc.
   I've written a short blog post about my custom modified MonoSingletone which can also live through scenes:
   http://gamedevrant.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/unity-and-singleton-design-pattern.html

Regarding performance, both classes can easily work and get called hundreds of time per frame even on mobile devices - so it's definitely a question of the right tool for your specific problem.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!